# JavaFX 2.2 content of ScrollPane too high?

Tags: performance, charts, drawing, javafx-2

I use javaFX 2.2 to draw **Gantt chart**. 
In the **left** side of SplitPane is editable **TableView with scheduled Tasks** (name, start,end),
 the **right** side is pannable **ScrollPane containing chart**. 
 I have an **ObservableList of Tasks** added to the table and, in a loop, for every Task in List I create Rectangle Node and add it to the ScrollPane. **Rectangles representing Tasks** in chart have to be interactive and listen to events so that they can move left/right, resize horizontally etc and this **properties are bind to the corresponding Task** object, so whenever I move Rectangle, the start/end of Task changes etc and when I edit cell in table , the corresponding Rectangle changes. TableView is scrolling vertically together with ScrollPane...

All seems to work well and smooth if I have up to 100 Tasks, but when I have more than that, dragging Rectangles (not ScrollPane) is very slow and takes a lot of CPU, and when there's more than 300, the app crashes...
How could I use Threads and what would be the best solution to handle events? **Lazy binding, Worker thread**, something else?

Or is this approach I just described good at all? 
Should I use **Canvas**? 
I'm new to javaFX and GUI programming
Thank you for answers!

**EDIT:**
The count of Nodes is not the problem, the problem is the size of content in scrollPane.
Each Task represented by Rectangle has constant height 24px, the same as row in tableView. 
So when I have many tasks, the height of the content in scrollPane gets too big, I found it out yesterday, so I need to implement dynamic content loading or something...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19577276/132374, you may be able to solve your problem just by setting 'cache' to true for your Nodes.  This causes them to be cached as images which graphics acceleration works very well with.

Details about 'cache':
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#cacheProperty